# How to remove a field from a Angular Reactive Form?

Tags: json, angular, rest, api, angular-reactive-forms

The Angular form I want to sent to the Api has 4  fields: username, email, password and confirmpassword. I want to send to the APi only three of them: username, email and password.

Any ideas how to delete the confirmpassword from the object?

Thank you!

This is how the object looks like:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        username:        ['', Validators.required],
        email:           ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password:        ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
        confirmpassword: ['', [Validators.required]]
    }, {
        validator: MustMatch('password', 'confirmpassword')
    });
}
```

And this is the object which I send to the APi at the moment:

```
this.userService.registerUser(JSON.stringify(this.registerForm.getRawValue()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the need to delete the form control. You can just delete the property from the object you get from the form. Also I see no need to use `getRawValue()`, since you have no disabled fields. So on submit I suggest:

```
onSubmit() {
  delete this.registerForm.value.confirmpassword;
  // ...
}
```

or you can pass the value of the form in the submit already:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm.value)"
```

and function:

```
onSubmit(values) {
  delete values.confirmpassword;
  // ...
}
```

and if you are doing a http-request, you don't need to stringify the value, just pass it as an object.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the property on that object. First make a copy of the object to be safe.

```
const formCopy = Object.assign({}, this.registerForm.getRawValue()); // copy form object
delete formCopy.confirmpassword; // delete property

this.userService.registerUser(JSON.stringify(formCopy));
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a disable property which would do that, let me show you how:

Assuming this is your submit method, just before sending it to the API, I'll remove the key by using the disable property.

```
public submitForm(): void {
    this.registerForm.get('confirmpassword').disable();
    console.log(this.registerForm.value)
}
```

In the console I'll get the three properties and here's a stackblitz which you can check, just made it now:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/remove-key-reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a field in an object using delete operator.

```
let formObj = this.registerForm.getRawValue();

delete formObj.confirmpassword;

this.userService.registerUser(JSON.stringify(formObj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use with model binding as follow

Create Register model

```
export class RegisterModel {
    username: string;
    email: string;
    password: string;
}
```

Use this register model binding to send body to your API

```
    this.model = new RegisterModel();
    this.model.username= this.registerForm.controls['username'].value;
    this.model.email= this.registerForm.controls['email'].value;
    this.model.password= this.registerForm.controls['password'].value;
```

And now send this model to your API

```
this.userService.registerUser(this.model)
```